# On $[0,1]$ does $f_n = \frac{nx}{1+nx^2}$ converge uniformly?

Tags: real-analysis, uniform-convergence

I know that the sequence of functions converges pointwise to the following piece-wise function $$
f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{x}, & 0<x\leq 1 \\
0, & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$ 
but I suspect that it does not display uniform convergence.

Comment: The uniform limit of a sequence of continuous functions is continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Take $x=1/n$.  Then

$$|f_n(x)-f(x)| = \Big|\frac{n}{n+1} - n\Big|$$

does not converge, so there is no uniform convergence.